# Pyxll file format and extension error on opening Excel

Tags: pyxll

I have been trying to add Pyxll add-in to excel but have run into considerable issues. I have tried to install the add-in through canopy and the standard zip file. I get the file onto my computer, add it to the add-in list, and then re-open excel and receive the following error:
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xk0my.png)

Then when I click yes this happens:[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8CtTt.png)

I have tried multiple things:
 - remove anything that might be holding it up from a trust perspective
 - I have attempted a different add-in that ran fine

Specs:
 - excel 2016
 - 64bit cpu
 - Windows 10

Answer (score 0):

Have you unzipped the downloaded pyxll package? Inside the zip file you should find a file called pyxll.xll, and that's the file you need to use.

The other thing to check is that you definitely are using Excel 2010 64 bit, as usually that error is caused by using the 64 bit addin with 32 bit Excel or vice versa. To check, go to File -> Help and on the right hand side you'll see "About Microsoft Excel". Just below there is the version number and in brackets after the version number it will say 64-bit if it is the 64 bit version. If it doesn't say that then you will need to install the 64 bit version of Office (or the 32 bit version of PyXLL and Python).

You can find full instructions on how to install PyXLL here:
https://www.pyxll.com/docs/quickstart.html